# NULL Pointer Exception in Hadoop's WritableComparator

Tags: java, design-patterns, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to calculate word frequency and using the order inversion design pattern.

Here is my Java code :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WordFreq2 {

   static enum StatusCounters {MAP_COUNTER, REDUCE_COUNTER, TOTAL_WORDS}    
   static enum MyExceptions {IO_EXCEPTION, INTERRUPTED_EXCEPTION, NULL_POINTER_EXCEPTION}

   public static class MyComparator extends WritableComparator {

      public int compare(WritableComparable a, WritableComparable b) 
      {
            if (a.toString().equals("special_key0") && b.toString().equals("special_key1") )
                return 0;
            else
            if ( a.toString().equals("special_key0") || a.toString().equals("special_key1") )
                return -1;
            else
            if ( b.toString().equals("special_key0") || a.toString().equals("special_key1") )
                return 1;
            else
                return a.toString().compareTo(b.toString());
      }
   }

   public static class MyPartitioner extends Partitioner<Text,IntWritable>
   {
        public int getPartition(Text key, IntWritable value, int num)
        {
            if ( key.toString().equals("special_key0") )
                return 0;
            else
            if ( key.toString().equals("special_key1") )
                return 1;
            else
                return key.hashCode() % num;
        }
   }


   public static class MyMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

     private Text word = new Text();
     private final int MEMORYHASHSIZE = 7;
     private final HashMap<String,Integer> memoryHash = new HashMap<String,Integer>(MEMORYHASHSIZE);
     private int special_key_count = 0;

     protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

     } 

     protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            flushMap(context);

            for ( int c = 0; c < context.getNumReduceTasks(); c++)
            {
                word.set("special_key"+c);
                context.write(word,new IntWritable(special_key_count)); 
            }
    } 

     private void flushMap(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
     {

            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = memoryHash.entrySet().iterator();        
            while (entries.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = entries.next();
                word.set(entry.getKey());
                context.write(word,new IntWritable(entry.getValue()));
                entries.remove();
            }   
     }

     protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

       String line = value.toString();
       StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);

       context.progress(); //in case of long running code, report that something is happening

       while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) 
       {

         String current_token = tokenizer.nextToken();

         // Key Present in our In-Memory Hash Tbale
         if ( memoryHash.containsKey(current_token) )
         {
             // Increase the corresponding counter
             Integer val = memoryHash.get(current_token);
             memoryHash.put(current_token,++val);
         }
         else
         {
             // Flush the HashTable if size limit reached
            if ( memoryHash.size() == MEMORYHASHSIZE)
                flushMap(context);

            memoryHash.put(current_token,1); // Make a new key with corresponding count 1 
         }

         special_key_count++;
         context.getCounter(StatusCounters.MAP_COUNTER).increment(1);
       }

     }
   }

   public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, FloatWritable> 
   {
     int total_words;

     protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         total_words=0;
     }

     protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         context.getCounter(StatusCounters.TOTAL_WORDS).increment(total_words);
     } 

     protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

       float frequency;

       for (IntWritable val : values)
       {
           if(key.toString().equals("special0") || key.toString().equals("special1"))
            {
                total_words = total_words + val.get();
            }
            else
            {
                frequency = val.get() / total_words; 
                context.write(key, new FloatWritable(frequency));
            }

       }

       context.progress(); //in case of long running code, report that something is happening
       context.getCounter(StatusCounters.REDUCE_COUNTER).increment(1);
     }

   }

   private static boolean deleteOutputDir(Job job, Path p) throws IOException {

     boolean retvalue = false;
     Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
     FileSystem myfs = p.getFileSystem(conf);
     if(myfs.exists(p) && myfs.isDirectory(p)) {
        retvalue = myfs.delete(p,true);
     }
     return retvalue;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Job job = Job.getInstance();
     job.setJarByClass(WordFreq2.class);
     job.setJobName("wordfreq");

     /* type of map output */
     job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class); 

     /* type of reduce output */
     job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     job.setOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);

     /* specify input/output directories */
     FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
     deleteOutputDir(job,new Path(args[1]));
     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

     /* How to read and write inputs/outputs */
     job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
     job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

     /* specify program components */
     job.setMapperClass(MyMap.class);
     job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

     job.setNumReduceTasks(2);     // Set the number of reducer to two

     job.setSortComparatorClass(MyComparator.class);
     job.setPartitionerClass(MyPartitioner.class);

     boolean result = job.waitForCompletion(true);

     Counters counters = job.getCounters();
     Counter acounter = counters.findCounter(MyExceptions.IO_EXCEPTION);
     long iocount = acounter.getValue();
     System.exit(result?0:1);
   }
}
```

However, I constantly hit this error :

```
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator.compare(WritableComparator.java:128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.compare(MapTask.java:1245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.QuickSort.sortInternal(QuickSort.java:74)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.QuickSort.sort(QuickSort.java:63)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1575)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:700)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:770)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

I am unable to figure out the issue. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Before `equals()` check, why not do null check like `a == null` and `a.toString() == null`?? How good practice usage like `"aString".equals(aString)` !!!

Comment: Can "a" be null? Wont hadoop call the method with valid keys as input?

Comment: I don't know hadoop invocation, just suggestion your coding way!!! And one more thing is your post of error stack track doesn't tell about your code.